# Is it mandatory to provide SCM Url for getting project ID in maven central

Tags: sonatype, maven-central

When Registering for Maven Central/central.sonatype.org is it mandatory to specify the Project URL/SCM URL.

I have a private github repo, but I want to publish my library on maven central. How can I do that ?

[image: Sonatype Form]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's required according to [the requirements](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html).

> The connection to your source control system is another required element.

In the [Maven guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html) it says

> What about artifacts that can't be distributed because of their license?
>   In that case only the POM for that dependency is required, listing where the dependency can be downloaded from. [See an example](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.0.2/activation-1.0.2.pom).